# Receiving data in xamarin with bluetooth

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, bluetooth

I am trying to receive bluetooth data that is send from my pic microcontroller (MCU). Upon reading the incoming data the data is split up (see picture).

[image: Datasplit]

[image]

How does this happen and how to resolve this problem?

Here is my code for receiving data:

```
public void beginListenForData()
    {
        try
        {
            inStream = btSocket.InputStream;
            streamReader = new StreamReader(inStream);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        int bytes = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((bytes = streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    string tekst = new string(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tekst);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bytes);
                    if (tekst == "D0O")
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        writeData("D2O");
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Vergelijking gelukt!");
                    }

                    streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
                }
            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this appears to be identical to your last question

Comment: Yea I know Changed it a bit but the other one seemed dead and no one was looking so I could wait for a long time but no answer would come so I hoped this would blow in new life

Comment: posting a duplicate is not the way to fix that.  Use a Bounty, or read the help section for ideas

Comment: Thanks didn't know that that existed :)